# Input + label syntax in SASS

Tags: css, sass

I was googling, but I didn't found any information about that question. If I have for example the following CSS:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background: #666;
    color: c00;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

Is there some different way to write it using **SASS** or the syntax will be the same as written in CSS? Like the nesting ..

And the other problem is when I want to take a speciffic label. So how to write that part in SASS when I want now to take the speciffic `label` with `type="one"` :

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + label[type="one"] {
    background: #666;
    color: c00;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using SASS, you may use both the same syntax you would use for CSS or decoupling your selectors according to the SASS nesting rules: e.g. you may also write

```
input[type="radio"]:checked {

    + label {
        background: #666;
        color: c00;
        height: 500px;
        width: 500px;
    }
}
```

Also for the second question you may write

```
input[type="radio"]:checked {
    + label[type="one"] {
       ...
    }
    /* other rules for element next to or nested in input:radio */
}
```

or

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    &[type="one"] {
       ...
    }
    /* other rules for labels with different attributes or classes */
}
```

or also

```
input[type="radio"]:checked {
    + label {
        &[type="one"] {
            /* other rules for elements nested into the label[type="one"] */
        }
        /* other rules for labels with different attributes or classes 
         * (or nested in a generic label) */
    }
    /* other rules for element next to or nested in input:radio */
}
```

depending on which form is more convenient for you. There's no a wrong or a right way to write the CSS code, just the way the makes you easier to write all the rules you need to define (writing just once the selectors you're writing more than once in plain CSS).

Comment: You only need half of those `&`.  You *do* need it if the previous selector and the current selector should not have a space between them (eg. `div { &.foo { .. } }` to get `div.foo { .. }`).  You *don't* need it if the selector can be written with a space (eg. `div { .foo { .. } }` to get `div .foo { .. }`)

Comment: It should be noted that unless you're actually injecting styles where the comments are located, there's no advantage to nesting it this way.  It just makes the processor do more work because it has to evaluate it all.