# Style label when input is checked using SASS

Tags: html, css, sass

I have HTML structure like this:

```
<div class="input__wrapper default__label__down">
  <div class="input__unit__wrapper">
    <input name="fabricColor" id="allegro_red_1" class="radioGroup__imageItem__input" type="radio" value="allegro_red_1">
    <span class="input__unit">mm</span>
  </div>

  <label class="radioGroup__imageItem__label" for="allegro_red_1">
      <img alt="allegro_red_1" src="IMG SRC" class="radioGroup__imageItem__label__image">
  </label>
</div>
```

How can I using SASS check if input (of type radio) is checked and then style img tag inside label?

Comment: You can go through this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14625655/8657746

Comment: @HamzaIftikhar, there is a problem with your solution. My input is in additional div, label is outside of this div.

Comment: Your comment explains why it can't be done in CSS (SASS is only a preprocessor so has the same problem). The input is not a parent or sibling of the element you want to style. For a CSS/SASS solution you'll need to restructure the HTML.

Comment:  I hope you understand what @AHaworth said. Brief and clear